# Does it holds that the $L^{\infty}$ norm of the support function of a convex body is minimal on balls with the same volume?

Tags: convex-geometry, isoperimetric-problems

I was wondering if the following inequality holds.

Let $K$ be a convex body of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let us denote by $h_K$ its support function, defined as, for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

$$ h_K(x)={\max}\{x\cdot y\;| y\in K \},$$
where $x\cdot y$ is the scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $B_R$ be the ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the same volume of $K$ (in  the sense of Lebesgue measure), where $R$ is its radius.

Is it true that there exists a positive constant $C=C(n)>0$ such that
$$ \|h_K \|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{S^n})}\geq C \|h_{B_R}\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{S^n})}(=C R)?$$

Do you have some reference for this inequality? Is it perhaps an easy consequence of the Alexandrov-Fenchel inequalities?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is no $C$ in the inequality. Also, the support function of the ball with center $0$ and radius $R$ is $x \mapsto R |x|$ (the Euclidean norm), so how can the norm be $1/R$ ? What do you mean by $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ ?

Comment: @GuillaumeAubrun Thank you! I have edited the question

Comment: But a support function is never bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Do you mean $L^{\infty}(S^{n-1})$ ?

Comment: @GuillaumeAubrun Sorry, yes!

Comment: In that case, the inequality is completely elementary (with $C=1$) once you notice that $\|h_K\|_{\infty}$ is equal to $\max \{ |x| \, :\, x \in K \}$. It is immediate that at given volume, balls centered at the origin minimize this parameter.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was asked and answered at Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4098045/does-it-holds-that-the-l-infty-norm-of-the-support-function-of-a-convex-bod